# printing color character in bash and the verbatim of another color character

Tags: bash

I have two color characters:

```
a="\033[38;5;154ma"
b="\033[38;5;199mb"
```

I can print them to the terminal, like:

```
printf "$a$b\n"
```

Likewise, I print them verbatim with echo:

```
echo $a
echo $b
```

But how do I do both at the same time. For example, I would like to do:

```
printf "$a$(echo $b)\n"
```

But this doesn't just execute "echo", it also executes the output of "echo" and thus colors the letter b instead of printing verbatim. I want to print a string where $a has been colored and $b is verbatim and not colored, something like `a\033[38;5;199mb`.

Comment: Are you looking for this? `printf "%b\n%b\n" "$a" "$b"`

Comment: No I want the string "a\033[38;5;199mb" to print. Here the "a" got colored, but the "b" includes verbatim the color. Run printf "$a$b\n" and echo $a$b.

Comment: Didn't try it myself, but from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code, I would conclude that _ESC [ m_ would turn off colouring. See the section about "SGR parameters" in that wiki.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
printf '%b\033[m%s\n' "$a" "$b"
```

Comment: oh wow, that works. But why did that work?

Comment: @Bobby %b interprets escape sequences, %s doesn't. It's all written in the manual

Comment: @BobbyOcean `help printf`

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [this](https://github.com/vaniacer/bash_color) for color printing. Here is how it works, color codes stored in variables:

```
red='\e[91m' #Red
grn='\e[92m' #Green
blu='\e[94m' #Blue
DEF='\e[0m'  #Default color and effects 
...
```

To print something with color simple add some color var before the text you wish to print in color:

```
printf "${red}R${grn}G${blu}B${DEF}no color"
```

[image]

Note the use of `$DEF` code without it this will be printed:

[image]